# Matlab script "sample time period" error when calling Simulink model

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am writing a Matlab script to call my Simulink model :

```
Constant10=43;
Constant11=43;
In1=[1,2,3];
In2=[4,5,6];
t_stop = 100;
T_s = t_stop/1000;
options = simset('solver', 'ode5', 'fixedstep', T_s);
sim('test_lau.slx',t_stop,options)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error using test_call_model (line 18)
The sample time period (0.01) of 'test_lau/INES0' is not an integer multiple of the fixed step size (0.1) specified for model.
```

Does anyone know how to solve it? I tried adding the line
`T_s= int64(T_s)`
But I have the same issue...

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone answered it for me!

Because 'test_lau/INES0' this block sample time (0.01) is lower than model sample time.
It sould be multiple of the fixed step size (0.1) specified for model.
there are 2 options
1)set model sample time as 0.01
2)set 'test_lau/INES0' sample time as inherit ot 0.1